# awk command returning on middle line

Tags: awk

Write an awk script that will take in a list of animals - such as the following - and output random combinations as a new creature. In the effort of comedy, you are allowed to add your own hilarious animal names to the input file to rearrange.

[instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgmq5.jpg)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create an awk script that will take in a list of animals - such as the following - and output random combinations as a new creature. In the effort of comedy, you are allowed to add your own hilarious animal names to the input file to rearrange

##comment created awk script generates 2 random numbers 
##comment the random numbers represent the line of text from where the words are to be taken
BEGIN { FS = "," }
    BEGIN {
        n1 = int(rand()*39);
        n2 = int(rand()*39);
    }
    {
        if ( NR == n1 ){
            printf("%s ",$1)
        }
        if ( NR == n2 ){
            printf("%s ",$1)
        }
    }
```

my script works, my issue is that the results come back to a command line on next line in middle of the screen. and it mixes up the random words without pairing it with animal type , any other recommendations?

Comment: Append a newline? I'm not sure your script does work. Output isn't very random.

Comment: plus it doesnt grab the animal typen I just relized

Comment: Suggest reading though the file saving animal names in an indexed array (e.g. `array[n++] = $1`), then using the `END` rule, loop as many times as you like and `print array[rand() % n] array[rand() % n] `. That way you can generate as many new animals as you like. (you can replace `array` with `animal` if you want a descriptive array name)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin isn't `rand()%n` a float?

Comment: Convert to `int` as needed. You are correct. With `rand()` `"The values of rand() are uniformly distributed between zero and one. The value could be zero but is never one"` The needed expression is `print array[int(rand() * n)]`

Comment: In place of the existing printf command?